# Upload de Imagens

Tags: php, ajax, back-end

Não tenho tanto conhecimento na área de back-end, mas preciso de um uploader de imagens, procurei uma maneira que não use banco de dados, mas acredito que seja impossível.

Preciso de um uploader semelhante ao do [Froala editor](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor), resolvi observar melhor o código do dele para entender um pouco mais como funciona, descobrir que ele usa uma url ( http://i.froala.com/upload ) para fazer um upload **temporário** das imagens, então como sou limitado na area de back-end descobrir [um projeto no GitHub](https://github.com/LPology/Simple-Ajax-Uploader) mas estou com problemas em configurar.

Então preciso de ajuda para configura-lo porque sou leigo nessa área. Quais dados eu preciso para configurar um uploader de imagens? , É possível usar a mesma url de upload temporário do Froala nele?, ou precisa de algum dado a mais do servidor? não é uma atitude muito boa mas preciso de algo provisório.

Se tiverem outras opções a me recomendar, fiquem a vontade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

é totalmente possível um upload de imagem sem banco de dados, se é para armazenar num diretório dentro de sua hospedagem, ou em uma pasta do seu projeto local, tudo o que tem que fazer é recuperar os dados do arquivo via php, e especificar um diretório destino, se for muito leigo, tente usar alguma coisa que facilite, veja esse plugin:

http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ *(ps: o plugin é estatico, ainda precisa manipular o arquivo via php)*

e veja alguns [tutoriais na internet](http://tableless.com.br/upload-de-arquivos-com-php/)

Comment: Em parte essa resposta resolveu meu problema, o autor deste plugin que você me enviou havia feito outro, especifico para load de imagens, fica aqui o link para se por acaso isso ajudar alguém no futuro com o mesmo problema que eu https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image

De qualquer forma, muito obrigado. o/